# Gnome-software losing installed software

Tags: gnome, software-center, 20.04, gnome-software

I've updated to the latest Ubuntu 20.04. I have been seeing that the `gnome-software` application is not showing the applications that I have installed. The applications do show when I kill `gnome-software` through the terminal like so `sudo killall gnome-software` and then reopen it. It is very annoying that I have to do this all the time. I initially thought this was a one time thing but now it has become frequent.

How do I make `gnome-software` show my applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some old configuration files were modified and these modifications are not compatible with newer gnome-software package and its dependencies. So to resolve it, you could try the next:

- Reinstall `gnome-software` and maybe dependent packages with purging:

  ```
  sudo apt purge gnome-software
  sudo apt install gnome-software
  ```
- Create new user and check if for new user you observe the same picture. If no, it means your user's configuration files are somehow not compatible with `gnome-software` package or something is not loaded before `gnome-software` starting the first time.

Comment: I didn't edit any old configuration files. didn't really touch gnome-software before until now

Comment: You don't, applications do.

Comment: I see. I'll reinstall and get back to you about this